Typing of Array in C structure is "overflowing" into subsequent fields?
I have the following types:
typedef float vec4[4]; // from cglm
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    float expand;
    vec4 color;
    Node *children;
}

For some reason, the color field's float[4] type is.. overflowing? into the fields after it. For example, when using the following literal:
Node test1 = (Node) { 
   .expand = 1.0f,
   .color = (vec4) { 0, 0, 1, 1 },
   .children = NULL
};

The compiler thinks that the color and children fields both ought to be single floats?:

error: initializing 'float' with an expression of incompatible type 'vec4' (aka 'float[4]')
error: initializing 'float' with an expression of incompatible type 'void *'

How do I properly provide the float[4] value within this structure literal, without breaking subsequent fields?

You're also missing a semicolon at the end of the definition of struct Node.

When asking question like this, present a single sequence of C code that can be compiled to reproduce the problem with no changes or insertions. For this case, that means do not interrupt the code with additional text (“For some reason…”), paste exactly the code that reproduces the problem (you have a missing ; after the definition of struct Node), and include necessary include directives (you need #include <stddef.h> or other header to get a definition of NULL). This makes it easier for other people to test the problem and ensure they are writing a correct answer.

You don't need the (Node) in the initializer — remove that too.

(vec4) { 0, 0, 1, 1 } is a compound literal that is indeed an array. However, you cannot initialize an array using an array (except for string literals), just as you cannot assign an array to an array. Arrays have never been first-class objects in C that can be operated on as a single thing; they have always been an aggregate of multiple things. Additionally, compound literals were added to the language late.
The grammar for initializing an array is to list the initial values of its elements in braces. So simply change .color = (vec4) { 0, 0, 1, 1 }, to .color = { 0, 0, 1, 1 },.
